# bxslider - slide overlap - two slides showing in 1 frame

Tags: javascript, html, css, video, bxslider

This issue with BX slider is driving me mad. I'm pretty much a novice when it comes to this.
I'm referring to this page > http://jimmyhunter.co.uk/cw.html (there are others where this issue appears too)

The first 4 slides are jpegs; all 1200px x 803px, which is the size of the BX wrapper.
The 5th slide is an MP4 video that doesn't fill the above dimensions.
What this does is display the top of slide No.1 below the video (in this case a jpeg with intro text.

The following slides also have similar videos but the 'slide overlap' only occurs on the first video.

Everything I try either doesn't work or fixes this slide but pushes the problem to the next video.

Thanks in advance. If you need more info, please let me know
Any ideas gratefully received.

Answer (score 0):

I've spotted an anomalous piece of code in your slider setup. If you look at the source code of your slider you should see this code on around line 89:

```
<span style="min-width:800px; display:block; margin:0 auto"><video  width="640" height="360" controls>
```

That "min width" is causing your problem I think. Get rid of it [edit: the entire span tag that is] and the closing `</span>` tag on around line 92. Take out the `width="640" height="360"` from the video tag too like the rest of the videos.

I did this in chrome devtools and got the following result:

http://picpaste.com/pics/Screen_Shot_2014-05-22_at_12.38.11-j7DM4t7S.1400758772.png

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Exactly you have not show here your problem but
I think If you follow the below structure it will helpful to you

**html**

```
<div class="slider">
    <ul>
        <li>your video</li>
        <li><img>.....</img></li>
        <li><img>.....</img></li>
        <li><img>.....</img></li>
        <li>your video</li>
        <li><img>.....</img></li>
        <li><img>.....</img></li>
        <li>your video</li>
    </ul>    
</div>
```

**css**

```
.slider{float:left:width:100%;}
.slider ul,.slider ul li,.slider ul li img,.slider ul li video,.slider ul li iframe{float:left:width:100%;}
```

*it will work perfectly if you are using full width slider and if not full width then wrap fixed width container

Answer (score 0):

html

```
<div class="bxslider">
    <ul>
        <li><img src="img1.jpg"></img></li>
        <li><img src="img2.jpg"></img></li>
   </ul>    
</div>
```

css

```
 .bxslider li{display:none;}
```

All elements will be hidden, only the current one will be displayed, bxslider uses inline css to display current slide. It should work.